# Return results mongoose in find query to a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to return the results of a query with mongoose in node.js.

How do you return the value to set the value to a variable?

What I need to do is:

```
var results = users.findOne({_id : users_list[i]['user_id']},{email : 1, credits : 1},{}, function(err, docs) {
    if( err || !docs) {
        console.log("No user found");
    } else {            
        return docs;
    };
});
```

In order to have:

```
results = docs
```

Thanks a lot for your reply .

I also have another problem.

How to pass variable in a query operator with find or findOne? Like :

```
var foo = "Blaa";

users.findOne({_id : users_list[i]['user_id']},{email : 1, credits : 1},{}, function(err, docs) {
    if( err || !docs) {
        console.log("No user found");
    } else {
        // I want to use the foo variable here
        console.log(foo);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want.

**1. Using Mongoose Queries**

In this strategy, your function returns a Mongoose query which you can later use to invoke the method `exec` and use it to get the results.

```
function getJedisQuery(name){
   var query = Jedi.find({name:name});
   return query;
}
```

Then you can use it simply doing:

```
var query =  getJedisQuery('Obi-wan');
query.exec(function(err,jedis){
   if(err)
      return console.log(err);
   jedis.forEach(function(jedi){
      console.log(jedi.name);
   });
});
```

**2. Using Mongoose Promise-like Objects**

Moogose provides support for promise-like objects. All you have to do is something somewhat similar to what I did above, but this time, you invoke the `exec` method without a callback.

```
function getJedisPromise(name){
   var promise = Jedi.find({name:name}).exec();
   return promise;
}
```

Then you can use it by simply doing:

```
var promise = getJedisPromise('Luke');
promise.then(function(jedis){
   jedis.forEach(function(jedi){
      console.log(jedi.name);
   });
})
```

As highlighted in the comment section of this answer, these objects are not in fact promises and that needs to be taken into account (see [Queries are not promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)).

**3. Using Mongoose Streams**

Finally, Mongoose has also support for streams and streams are event emitters. So, you could get a stream and then subscribe for 'data' and 'error' events. Like this:

```
function getjedisStream(name){
   var stream = Jedi.find({name:name}).stream();
   return stream;
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
var stream = getJedisStream('Anakin');
stream.on('data', function(jedis){
   jedis.forEach(function(jedi){
      console.log(jedi.name);
   });
});
stream.on('error', function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

[Source](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html), for future reference.

Comment: One small edit to your answer.

There is no .error function in mongoose promises.
It gives the following error when I use it - TypeError: promise.then(...).error is not a function nodejs

If we want error handling then we should do something like
mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;
and then use the function .catch(function(err) {

Comment: I know OP was happy with the answer, but you're not actually explaining how to put the result in a `results` variable that can be used in the rest of the code.

Comment: @vivekp: I'm also getting same TypeError. Kindly update the working code here

Comment: The mongoose docs say that a Query is not a Promise https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises

Answer (score 9):

It is being executed before the assignment.

```
 async function(req, res) {
      var user;
      await users.findOne({}, function(err,pro){
          user=pro;
        });
      console.log(user); \\ it's define
    };
```

Comment: Looks like the last closing parens ) is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this.

```
const getUser = async ( req, res ) => {
   let users = () => ( User.find({_id : users_list[i]['user_id']},{email : 1, credits : 1}).exec() );

   try { res.send({"user":await users() });}
   catch(e) { console.log(e) } 
}

app.get('/user' , getUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

You achieve the desired result by the following code. Hope this will helps you a lot..

```
var async = require('async');

// custom imports
var User = require('../models/user');
var Article = require('../models/article');

var List1Objects = User.find({});
var List2Objects = Article.find({});
var resourcesStack = {
    usersList: List1Objects.exec.bind(List1Objects),
    articlesList: List2Objects.exec.bind(List2Objects),
};

async.parallel(resourcesStack, function (error, resultSet){
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
        return;
    }
    res.render('home', resultSet);
});
```