# Async parallel Issue

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm trying to get the result of all the functions 'getSlotCount' using Async - each getSlotCount returns a single JSON object using Schema's .find() correctly, but due to the async behaviour, only after I need to utilise the results.

I've tried it a few different ways, but to no effect. What is it i'm doing wrong?

```
async.parallel({
            small: function(callback){
                var small = getSlotCount('1-50');
                callback(null, small);
            },
            medium: function(callback){
                var medium = getSlotCount('200');
                callback(null, medium);
            },
            large: function(callback){
                var large = getSlotCount('1000');
                callback(null, large);
            }
        },
        function(err, results) {
            var availability = {
                'large': results.large,
                'medium': results.medium,
                'small': results.small
            };
            console.log(availability);
            res.json([availability]);
        });
```

Comment: if you post your `getSlotCount()` function, I'm happy to edit my answer to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

The `.find()` function doesn't "return" a JSON Object, it passes it to a callback:

```
Model.find({_id: "1234"}, function(err, result) {
    // here is your result
}
```

vs.

```
var result = Model.find({_id: "1234"});
// result is a query object, not the response from that query
```

Again, these are assumptions based on having no knowledge of `getSlotCount()`, but if it's actually asynchronous, your code should look more like:

```
async.parallel({
            small: function(callback){
                getSlotCount('1-50', callback);
            },
            medium: function(callback){
                getSlotCount('200', callback);
            },
            large: function(callback){
                getSlotCount('1000', callback);
            }
        },
        function(err, results) {
            var availability = {
                'large': results.large,
                'medium': results.medium,
                'small': results.small
            };
            console.log(availability);
        });
```

Comment: This was very helpful! Pointing out that the result is a query not the response led me to find the right answer. 

Thank you!

Here's the stack overflow that helped me complete this - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035872/return-results-mongoose-in-find-query-to-a-variable