# Why i can't get return value in MEAN?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I have the following code on a db.js script:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbConnect = Mongoose.connection;

dbConnect.on('errorers', console.error);
dbConnect.once('open', function() { console.log('Conectado ao MongoDB.'); });
var conex = Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test2');

var db = function() {
    var Usuario = require('./model/User.js'),
        Config = require('./model/Config.js'),
        //USER

        buscarConfig = function(){
            Config.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, data){
                if(!err){
                    console.log(data[0]);
                    return data[0];
                } else{
                    //console.log(err);
                    return err;
                }
            });
        },
        killConex = function(){
            conex.disconnect();
        };

    return {
        BC: buscarConfig,
        del: killConex
    };
};
module.exports = db;
```

And then i have the following on another script:

```
dbModel = require('./data/db.js')();
teste = dbModel.BC();
console.log(teste);
```

But all i get is undefined return, even getting it printed on the first console.log.

I guess i'm on a miss concept but can't figure it out where.

Comment: You can't return results from a callback.

Comment: How is that? What would be the proper way?

Comment: You have to design your API to accept a callback, just like everything else in the Node world. Then you invoke that callback from the function you pass to the lower-level service.

Comment: you could return futures/promises from your callback

Comment: Im trying to find information on how to do it, but i might be asking the wrong questions. I see its a javascript "issue", the way i built my object, right?

Comment: Ok, got it, not clear yet why but found this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035872/return-results-mongoose-in-find-query-to-a-variable) and got it to work. Thanks for the tips!