# Return result of mongoose find query to an outside variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good day.
I know that similar questions have been already asked, however, I haven't found an answer. Let's presume there's a mongo DB with tests collection. I make a query to this collection and then I need to save the result of this query to a variable so that it can be used in the rest of the code.
Here're what I've tried:

```
//method #1
var result = Test.find({}, (err,data) => {
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }else{
    return data;
  }
});
console.log(result); //return huge array with information about collection, but not values

//method #2
function getResult() {
  Test.find({}, (err,data) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }else{
      return data;
    }
  })
};
var result = getResult();
console.log(result); //return undefined

//method #3
async function getResult() {
  const data = await Test.find({});
  return data;
}
var result = getResult();
console.log(result); //return Promise { <pending> }
```

I also tried answers, provided to this question [Return results mongoose in find query to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24035872/13808925)

```
// method #4
function getResult(){
  var query = Test.find({});
  return query;
};
var query =  getResult();
query.exec(function(err,names){
   if(err)
      return console.log(err);
   names.forEach(function(name){
     console.log(name) //return array with values
   });
});
console.log(query); //return huge array with information about collection, but not values

//method#5
function getResult(){
  var promise = Test.find({}).exec();
  return promise;
};
var promise = getResult();
promise.then(function(names){
   names.forEach(function(name){
      console.log(name); //return array with values
   });
});
console.log(promise); //return Promise { <pending> }
```

None of these methods returned a query result to the variable outside of a function, which can be used further in code.
I'll much appreciate any help.

First off, thanks a lot for replies.
@Raghuveer

```
//Method 2: 
function getResult() {
      Test.find({}, (err,data) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(data); //return values array but it's ony inside function
            return data
        }
      })
    };
    var result = getResult();
    console.log(result); //return undefined
```

Method #3: something like this?

```
//method #3
async function getResult() {
  const data = await Test.find({});
}
async function saveResult() {
  var result = await getResult();
}
```

But then how can I get result from this and save it to a variable?

POST route

```
//CREARE job event
app.post('/scheduler/jobEvent', (req,res) => {
    var personnelTitle = req.body.event.title,
        start = req.body.event.start + 'T12:00',
        end = req.body.event.end + 'T12:00',
        resourceId = req.body.event.resourceId,
        projectId = req.body.event.projectId;
        projectTitle = Resource.findOne({id: projectId}, (err,query) => {
             if(err) throw(err);
             return query;
        }); //Here I try to get 'title' from document and return this value to projectTitle variable       

    var newJobEvent = {projectTitle: projectTitle, title: personnelTitle, start: start, end: end, resourceId: resourceId};

    Event.create(newJobEvent, (err, createdEvent) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Event 2 created')
        res.redirect('back');
    });
});
```

> Solution

```
app.post('/scheduler/jobEvent', async (req,res) => {
    var start = req.body.event.start + 'T12:00',
        end = req.body.event.end + 'T12:00',
        jobResourceId = req.body.event.resourceId,
        projectId = req.body.event.projectId;
        //query to DB and get project title
        foundProject = await Resource.findOne({id: projectId}, 'title'), 
        projectTitle = foundProject.title,
        //assemble new array
        newJobEvent = {title: personTitle, start: start, end: end, resourceId: jobResourceId, linkedEvent: personResourceId};
```

Comment: if you are in an async context, you could await method 3 like this: `var result = await getResult`. That way the variable will be set to whatever the promise resolved to.

Comment: I tried. It returns with SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.

Comment: Method 2:- you need to place your logic (console log) inside else, Method 3:- wrap your call of await getResult inside one more async function.

Comment: For method 5, put the console.log inside of the .then()

Comment: @Aniket Gargya There's console.log inside promise.then. But it works only inside this function. I need to use a query result outside of the function.

Comment: @Raghuveer Everything works great inside functions. But I need to get the query result out of function. Put resulted values in the variable that is outside of the function and use this variable later on.

Comment: Is there anything specific you want to do with the variable? It is hard to recommend a choice if I don't know what you want to do with the variable. You could use an async function

Comment: Here's what I try to make: js file sends a query to MongoDB, finds document by ID and retrieves 'title' from this document. Then I need to return the 'title' to `projectTitle` variable and along with other variables create an array `newJobEvent`. This array is used to create a new document in MongoDB. All these happen inside POST route. I added this code in question.

Comment: In javascript everything you write is by default inside a function, even if you have not created one. Create a main function of type async and consume other function, you can use await here. Also if you want to use this variable in other file make this main function as IIFE function.

Comment: What if you declare a global variable at the beginning of javascript file? As far as I understand you just declare place in memory with a variable name. Nothing about function.